# Idempotent AWS lambda does not execute code on cold start

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

### Problem

When I add the [Idempotency configuration of aws-lambda-powertools](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/latest/utilities/idempotency/) my function code is not executed propertly.

The AWS lambda serves as message handler for a MS Teams chatbot when the function performs a cold start the async code within the handler is not executed and no message is returned to the user. I also don't see any logs so it seems that the code in the async handler is not executed at all.

Could this be due to the way I handle my async handler?

### Code

```
@idempotent(persistence_store=persistence_layer, config=cfg)
def lambda_handler(event:dict, context: dict): 
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(lambda_messages(event))
    
    payload = json.loads(event["body"])
    
    return {"status": 400, "payload": payload}
```

Comment: That sounds like it could be a bug in aws-lambda-powertools. I suggest opening an issue for aws-lambda-powertools on Github. From my experience I know the folks there are pretty helpful and responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the timeout of my aws sam function not being configured properly. Because of aws-labmda-powertools it was hard to debug as the error was not easily vissible.

Answer (score 0):

Powertools maintainer here. As of 2.x, we've improved error messages for Idempotency and other features too: https://github.com/aws-powertools/powertools-lambda-python/pull/1813

We also improved our docs to include sequence diagrams for all scenarios Idempotency take, so it makes it easier to debug in the future too.

https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda-python/latest/utilities/idempotency/#idempotency-request-flow